# How can I make the width of an image in a Shiny app dynamic?

Tags: css, r, image, shiny

I am writing an app and I want the image in the sidebarPanel to be just a bit bigger than the image I put inside it. As the window gets smaller or larger, so does the sidebar, but the image stays static. How do I fix this problem? Is there a way to get the sidebar length or is there a better way to render images?

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Sidebar Image App"),
   sidebarPanel(
      imageOutput("image", height = "auto")
   )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   output$image <- renderImage({
      return(list(
         src = "one.png",
         contentType = "image/png",
         height = 185,
         alt = "Face"
      ))
   })
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can style the image using css tag as below:

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
    titlePanel("Sidebar Image App"),

    tags$head(tags$style(
        type="text/css",
        "#image img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto}"
    )),

    sidebarPanel(
        imageOutput("image")
    )
)),
```

where css id selector (here `#image`) should correspond to the `outputId` of the `imageOutput`.

Comment: How do you add the image source?